# cloud-init script with args (parametrized)

Tags: deployment, cloud-init

### Long Story

I'm preparing cloud-init scripts for instaling [monitoring software agent](https://github.com/whitehats/monitowl-agent) (*disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of MonitOwl*). The agent software collect information (like memory or network stats) and send it to server. Each company group should connect to own *personalized* server URL like: https://customer_name.example.org.

The cloud-init script is a `Content-Type: multipart/mixed;` that downloads agent from github, install systemd service and install python requirements. Currently we use it like:

`# ec2-run-instances --user-data-file <our_generated_file>`

For our internal deployments we use ansible (parametrized with VARS) but now more and more people ask for cloud-init script.

### Goal

I would like to have one common cloud-init script for all companies and just provide argument with URL to server. I would like to put this cloud-init script in our github repository, to make the experience of installing agent even better.

### Problem

Unfortunately the only way I found is to prepare a separate script - [generator](https://github.com/whitehats/monitowl-agent/blob/master/cloudinit-gen.sh) that will create the cloud-init script with hardcoded URL inside. Is there any nice way to accomplish my goal? I cannot believe that canonical didn't think about parametrization when developing cloud-init.

Comment: user-data string or user-data-file? [User configurability](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/capabilities.html#user-configurability)

Comment: @Brian: --user-data-file, take a look at our [current](https://github.com/whitehats/monitowl-agent/blob/master/cloudinit-gen.sh) implementation

Answer (score 2):

Long story short cloud-init can be templatized using jinja variables passed to it via the Metadata. Metadata then passed to the cloud-init instance, there are some good examples here:
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/instancedata.html

Please note that you will need to enable Metadata on instance creation.

To test the variables you may use one the the instances with metadata enabled.

```
[user@ubuntu-h~]$ cloud-init query -f "{{ sys_info.uname[1] }}"
ubuntu-h
```

That "ubuntu-h" was taken from metadata, not from the local machine.

Personally I had to generate salt-minion name based of the ec2 instance hostname. One could use module specific for it's application or runcmd. **Please note shebang for template as well as for cloud-config ↓**

```
## template: jinja
#cloud-config
runcmd:
    - ["/bin/mkdir", "-p", "/data/salt/etc"]
    - ["/bin/ln", "-s", "/data/salt/etc", "/etc/salt"]
    - echo 'test.{{ sys_info.uname[1] }}.aws.local' >> /etc/salt/minion_id

### OR using the module salt-minion:

salt_minion:
    pkg_name: 'salt-minion'
    service_name: 'salt-minion'
    config_dir: '/data/salt/etc'
    conf:
        master: IP_ADDRESS
        id: test.{{ sys_info.uname[1] }}.aws.local
        root_dir: /data/salt
        pki_dir: /pki/minion
        conf_file: /data/salt/etc/minion
        log_file: /data/salt/log/minion
        log_level_logfile: info
    grains:
        role:
            - aws_staged
```